# Logitech MK550 keyboard doesn't work with Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, logitech-keyboard

I bought a Logitech Wireless Wave Combo MK550 Keyboard recently and have been trying to use the keyboard with Windows 8 but it does not seem to work.

I am not sure if there is an issue with the driver.

Where I can download the drivers from?

Comment: What exactly does *it does not seem to work* mean?

Comment: I am not able to type anything. I tried connecting the usb to different port still no luck !!!

Comment: It's unlikely that a keyboard would require installing any driver to type (media buttons are a different story). Does your keyboard work in the BIOS? If it doesn't, there's a good chance it's broken.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if this is too obvious, but check that

1. The batteries are inserted and are the right way around.
2. The keyboard is switched on (there should be a button on the bottom)
3. The keyboard is close enough to the USB receiver

Answer (score 0):

Here are the latest drivers for Windows 8 for your model of Keyboard and Mouse.

http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/keyboard-mice-combos/wireless-wave-combo-mk550?section=downloads&bit=32&osid=23

Comment: Let me install the driver from the site and try to connect my keyboard !!!!